# python negative timedelta object

Tags: python, datetime, time, timedelta, pytz

I'm writing a python program that needs to do nothing between 23:00 and 8:00 depending on the time zone of the proxy it uses.

```py
proxy_zone = get_timezone()
proxy_timezone = pytz.timezone(proxy_zone)

proxy_time = datetime.now(proxy_timezone)
now_time = proxy_time.time()

if now_time >= datetime_time(23, 00) or now_time <= datetime_time(8, 00):

    future = datetime(proxy_time.year, proxy_time.month, proxy_time.day, 8, 0)
    if proxy_time.hour >= 8:
        future += timedelta(days=1)

    bed_time = (future.astimezone(proxy_timezone) - proxy_time)
    sleep(bed_time.total_seconds())
```

proxy_time is 6:45 so the timedelta (`future.astimezone(proxy_timezone) - proxy_time`) returns should be 1 hour and 45 minutes.

But instead I get a timedelta of -1 day and 4 and a half hours.

Comment: I think you should `localize` `future` to the time zone instead of *converting* it with `astimezone`. That would be `future.localize(proxy_timezone)` in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MrFuppes answered localizing the future converting the time to the correct timezone instead of localizing it was causing the issue.

```py
proxy_time = datetime.now(proxy_timezone)
now_time = proxy_time.time()

if now_time >= datetime_time(23, 00) or now_time <= datetime_time(8, 00):  # Sleep until 8:00

    future = datetime(proxy_time.year, proxy_time.month, proxy_time.day, 8, 0)
    if proxy_time.hour >= 8:
        future += timedelta(days=1)
        
    future = proxy_timezone.localize(future)
    bed_time = (future - proxy_time).total_seconds()

    event.nap(f'Sleeping for {bed_time} seconds')
    sleep(bed_time)  # sleep until morning
```